# tkinter picture error: "images may not be named same as on main window"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to write a tkinter version of flappy bird, and I came across an error that I've never seen before while working with tkinter. I've searched around everywhere, and tried everything I can think of. This is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, height=400, width=400)
canvas.pack()
bird = PhotoImage(root, file="L:\\Programming\\Python\\flappyBird\\bird.png")
```

and this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "L:\Programming\Python\flappyBird\flappyBird.py", line 5, in <module>
    bird = PhotoImage(root, file="L:\\Programming\\Python\\flappyBird\\bird.png")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3384, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3340, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: images may not be named the same as the main window
>>>
```

Comment: Wild guess: try `bird = PhotoImage(file="L:\\Programming\\Python\\flappyBird\\bird.png")`

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I hadn't tried that before. That worked, for some odd reason. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for `PhotoImage`, it doesn't look like supplying any positional arguments is recommended. Try creating it without the `root`.

```
bird = PhotoImage(file="L:\\Programming\\Python\\flappyBird\\bird.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

The first keyword argument in the PhotoImage constructor is `name`. By passing `root` as the first positional argument, it is being associated with the `name` keyword argument. Thus, you are trying to create a widget with the same name as the root window, hence the error "images may not be named the same as the main window"

Omit `root` as the first argument when creating the image and the problem will go away.